# Escape character before closing brascet is redundant

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I need to match some digits between curly brackets in string, my regex look like this: `SNC{(\\\d*)}`. 
After applying escape characters, I thought that regex should transform into `SNC\\\\{(\\\d*)\\\\}`, but Intellij's inspector is suggesting that escape backslashes before closing bracket  is redundant so `SNC\\\\{(\\\d*)}` is enough.  Why does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regex `{m,n}` is used as quantifier representing amount between `m` and `n` (inclusive). If you escaped first `{` like `\{..}` then regex engine will not treat rest of that subexpression as description of quantifier, so it is no longer *special* which allows us to skip escaping for `}`.

Although escaping such `}` is allowed - meaning your code will work - as you see some IDEs consider it as unnecessary and *warn* you about it.

---

BTW same rule applies to `\[...]` but NOT to `\(...)` - regex always expects `)` to be explicitly escaped *if you want to treat it as literal*.

*(Speculation:)*
I am guessing that this decision was based on fact that `(...)` (including look-around, named-groups, etc.) can be used very often in regex and be nested. So we often up with regex like `( \( ( ...) ( ) ) )` where noticing which `)` represents *literal* could be a a problem.